# Response to FHIR Query Messages

Tags: hl7-fhir

When performing a query message in FHIR I have a bundle with a **MessageHeader** linked to a **Query** resource

The FHIR spec states

> The receiver processes the message, and then returns a message with a message header, a query with response details, and either an error in the query response, or a set of resources that meet the query criteria. See the examples for an example query response message.

So does that mean that the **MessageHeader** "response" class is never used if the message is a query, as the response is actually within the **Query** resource itself?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the response MessageHeader points to the Query as the "response", and that contains everything. You could say that's not really necessary, but it just creates consistency across all message responses